# expanding flex to full width with cards BootStrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using flex to contain cards using bootstrap but the cards are not shown to the full width of the screen. They are stacked up on the left half of the screen.

The HTML file is this:

```
<section class="projects" id="projects">
            <div class="services-cards">
                <div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/undraw_develop_app_re_bi4i.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/undraw_for_review_eqxk.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/undraw_Success_factors_re_ce93.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </section>
```

And the css is as

```
.card{
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
     padding:10px;
  }
  .services-cards{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
    justify-items:auto;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm expecting that the content of the flexed (cards in this case) will be full width of the screen.

Right now it looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7nlM.png)

Comment: Do you want `.card` to  be full width of screen ?

Comment: .service-cards to be full screen width
As you can see I have 3 cards in service-cards. Those 3 cards I want to be spread out uniformly across the width of the screen. Right now, they are next to each other on the left half of the screen.

Comment: add `.services-cards:{justify-content:space-around}` or `justify-content:space-between` according to your need

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.justify-content-between` or `.justify-content-around` on `.service-cards`. *Between* will put the first and last at the far edges and evenly distribute the items between them, while *around* will make all the spaces on outsides and between equal.

```
<section class="projects" id="projects">
  <div class="services-cards justify-content-between">

    {card} {equal-space} {card} {equal-space} {card}

  </div>
</section>
```

Or

```
<section class="projects" id="projects">
  <div class="services-cards justify-content-around">
    
    {equal-space} {card} {equal-space} {card} {equal-space} {card} {equal-space}

  </div>
</section>
```